# Trying to show that $\phi(n) > c_1 \frac{n}{\text{log log }n}$ for some constant $c_1 > 0$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Trying to show that $\phi(n) > c_1 \frac{n}{\text{log log }n}$ for some constant $c_1 > 0$ where $\phi(n)$ is the euler phi function.

I was wondering if I could use something like

\begin{align}
\phi(n)\geq \frac{n}{e^{\gamma}\log \log n}+O\left(\frac{n}{(\log \log n)^2}\right)
\end{align}

to show this, but I'm not sure. Could anyone maybe give me some advice or tips on how to do this? I have quite a few Analytical Number Theory texts and notes with me, so even suggestions to some theorems would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Is the formula you give one that you already know or one that you are conjecturing?

Comment: one that I already know.

Comment: Then your result follows, since the first term dominates all other terms as $n \to \infty$, so that there always exists some $\epsilon$ such that $\phi(n)\geq \frac{n}{e^{\gamma}\log \log n}(1+\epsilon)$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty} \epsilon=0$ and for all $n>N$ for some $N$, $\epsilon$ is monotonic decreasing, from which the result follows.

Comment: See the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104955/bounds-of-eulers-totient-function).

Comment: @Laertes, if I needed to choose a constant $c_1$ that has to hold for all $n$, what would it be w.r.t. $\epsilon$?

Comment: $c_1={1+\epsilon \over e^\gamma}$ for the highest value of $\epsilon$ for any $n$. One value that appears to work for $c_1$ is $1\over 9$, although I haven't rigorously tested that.

Comment: perfect! Laertes your help has been invaluable, so I just let $c_1 = \text{lim }sup_{\epsilon}\left(\frac{1+\epsilon}{e^\gamma}\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

The best theorem to look up is, I think, the following effective lower bound for $\phi(n)$

**Theorem:** For all $n>2$ we have
$$
\frac{\phi(n)}{n}>\frac{1}{e^{\gamma}\log \log n+\frac{3}{\log \log n}}.
$$

Comment: If I prove this result, can I then say that $\frac{\phi(n)}{n} > \frac{1}{\text{loglog }n}\left(\frac{1}{e^\gamma+3}\right)$?

Comment: Also do you maybe have a link to a proof of this result?

Comment: Yes, it is the same link as above: see the answer with the link "LOWER" [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below).