# how prove $\phi(n)\ge \frac{n}{6\log \log (n)} $ $\forall n\ge5 $

Tags: number-theory, inequality, totient-function

How to prove$\forall n\ge5 $

> $$\phi(n)\ge \frac{n}{6\log \log (n)} $$

$\phi$ is Euler function

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101654/frac-n5-phi-n-n-for-all-n-1/101665#101665 for an even stronger result