# Derivation of the lower bound of Euler's Phi Function

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

In the answer to a different question titled ["Is the Euler phi function bounded below?",](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below) one answer derives the fact that if $0<\delta<1$, then $\frac{\phi(n)}{n^{1-\delta}}$ attains its minimum at $n=2\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot p=p\sharp$, where $p$ is the largest prime satisfying $p-1\le p^{1-\delta}$. Thus, for a given prime $p$, we can set $\delta=1-\log_p (p-1)$ to find that $\phi(n)\ge\phi(p\sharp)(\frac{n}{p\sharp})^{\log_p (p-1)}$. Is there a way to use this to derive the well-known inequality $\phi(n)\ge \frac{n}{e^\gamma\log\log{n}+\frac{3}{\log\log{n}}}$? If not, how is this inequality derived? Thank you.

Comment: You want Rosser and Schoenfeld 1962. It is available for free online. See if I can find it.  http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807

Comment: possible duplicate of [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101654/frac-n5-phi-n-n-for-all-n-1)

Answer (score 1):

A complete derivation of the lower bound can be found [in this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101665/6075)

$$  $$

Comment: How is this derived from the fact that $\phi(n)\geq \frac{n}{e^{\gamma}\log \log n}+O\left(\frac{n}{(\log \log n)^2}\right)$?