A general result for finite order matrices with integer coefficients?
The following question was given as an exercise in many orals for french preparatory classes:
Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that there exists $p \in \mathbb{N}^*$ with $A^p = I_2$.
Show that $A^{12} = I_2$
I showed this result by looking at the eigenvalues of $A$ and using the fact that its trace is an integer we can narrow down exactly what eigenvalues $A$ can have, and then we can conclude.
However, I want to generalize the exercise into this result:
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $A \in \mathcal{M_n}(\mathbb{Z})$, can we show that there exists a certain sequence $b_n$ such that if $A$ verifies the existence of $p$ such that $A^p = I_n$, then necessarily $A^{b_n} = I_n$ as well? Can we have a formula for $b_n$?
I have the following sketch of a proof, but am not satisfied with it as it does not really give any formula for $b_n$:
Suppose $A^p = I_n$ for some integer $p$, therefore the polynomial $P = X^p - 1$ annhilates $A$, meaning that $A$ is diagonalizable in $\mathbb{C}$ and its eigenvalues are all $p$-th roots of unity.
Let $\chi_A$ be $A$'s characteristic polynomial, we have $\displaystyle \chi_A = \prod_{\omega \in Sp(A)}\left(X-w \right)$, and $|\omega| = 1$
Additionally, each coefficient of $\chi_A$ is an integer, and from Vieta's formulas those coefficients are the sum of complex numbers of modulus $1$, therefore using triangle inequality each coefficient is bounded by some number (independent of $p$).
Therefore, we have only finitely many coefficients possible, and therefore only finitely many roots (eigenvalues) possible. Hence, there are only finitely many $p$'s such that $A^p = I_n$, and so taking $b_n$ to be the $\mathrm{lcm}$ of the possible $p$'s, we do get $A^{b_n} = I_n$
Already, is this proof correct? And is there a more constructive one that could actually build the sequence $b_n$?
So far, I've (possibly wrongly) calculated $b_2 = 12$ (from the exercise), $b_3 = 12$, and $b_4 = 120$
I've thought of using cyclotomic polynomials, but I'm really not comfortable enough with those to actually get anything done.

I'm sure you're right about $b_3$,since one of the ev is real and hence $\pm 1$ and then you're reduced to the $2\times 2$ calculation. And $b_4$ is certainly divisible by $60$ since the $5$-th roots of unity have a quartic minimal polynomial. I think the question is about cyclotomic polynomials.

I suppose you have looked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766108/describe-the-finite-order-integer-matrices-over-complex-field?rq=1

Looking at the question I have just referenced I think your  $b_4$ should be $120$. The companion of $X^4+1$ has order $8$.

I did see that question, but when it got into cyclotomic polynomials I kind of gave up...

There is a very interesting paper that kind of answers this question. Here is a link for it, you need to save the file as a pdf for it to work...
The useful theorem is Theorem 2.7, and a few examples are given at Example 2.10. It suffices to take the LCM of the possible orders to recover the $b_n$ we seek

Your argument works in the exact same way if $p$ is not prime, no? But you can’t just take a lcm of primes since, after all, $b_2$ is divisible by $4$…

Cyclotomic polynomials are in fact the key, you can see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370782/sum-of-the-coefficients-of-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-periodic-matrices/370793#370793 for some discussion.
